# react parent not re-rendering child despite state change

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, render, state

I have a DatePicker parent component that has a child SearchBar component. The SearchBar is an input that has an onChange, which is connected to DatePicker's handleSearchChange. The SearchBar will initialize with the current Date plugged in due to DatePicker passing its state of currentDateObj down. However, SearchBar's input should change from user input because it's onChange will change the state of DatePicker, which should in turn change SearchBar's input, but even with my console.logs I don't see SearchBar being re-rendered and the input keeps resetting itself to the initial date (today) rather than showing any change to user input.

```
//DatePicker
    var DatePicker = React.createClass({
          getInitialState: function () {
            var today = new Date();
            return {currentDateObj: today, searchInput: undefined};
          },
          handleSearchChange: function (e) {
            var inputString = e.target.value.toString();
            var inputRegex = /^\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}$/;
            if (inputRegex.test(inputString)) {
              var year = e.target.value[6]+e.target.value[7]+e.target.value[8]+e.target.value[9];
              var month = e.target.value[0]+e.target.value[1];
              var day = e.target.value[3]+e.target.value[4];
              var currentDateObj = new Date(year, month, day);
              this.setState({currentDateObj:currentDateObj });
            } else {
              this.setState({searchInput: inputString});
            }
          },
          render: function () {
            var datePickerComponent = this;
            var dateNextYearObj = new Date();
            var searchDateObj = this.state.searchInput === undefined ? this.state.currentDateObj : this.state.searchInput;
            console.log('hit datepick render');
            console.log(this.state.searchInput);
            dateNextYearObj.setFullYear(this.state.currentDateObj.getFullYear() + 1);
            return(
              <div>
                <SearchBar currentDateObj={searchDateObj} handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}/>
              </div>
            );
          }
        });
```

//SearchBar

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    console.log('hit searchbar render')
    var currentDateObj = this.props.currentDateObj;
    if(typeof (currentDateObj.getMonth) === "function"){

      var currentDate = currentDateObj.getDate().toString();
      if (currentDate.length === 1) {currentDate = "0" + currentDate;}

      var currentMonth = currentDateObj.getMonth().toString();
      if (currentMonth.length === 1) {currentMonth = "0" + currentMonth;}

      var currentYear = currentDateObj.getFullYear().toString();

      var formattedCurrentDate = currentMonth + "/" + currentDate + "/" + currentYear;
      return {currentDateObj: formattedCurrentDate};
    } else {

      return {currentDateObj: currentDateObj};
    }
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.props.handleSearchChange} value={this.state.currentDateObj}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Revised Answer

The getIntialState method is only invoked once when your component is first created so it will not be useful on subsequent renders.

You might want to stick the formatting logic somewhere else such as the render function or a more convenient lifecycle method such as [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops), which is the way I would do it. Let me know if that helps and best of luck.

---

#### Resources

- [Props in getInitialState Is an Anti-Pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)
- [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

---

#### Old answer:

> *No longer relevant due to [Autobind by Default](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html)*

You are likely losing your `this` binding when passing down the handler. Try this:

```
<SearchBar currentDateObj={searchDateObj} handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Check out all the cool ways you can manage your bindings in [this blog](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html) by [Igor Smirnov](http://egorsmirnov.me/). I use Babel to transpile my code and with the `stage-0` preset, I can simply use fat arrow functions in my class handler methods so I never have to worry about `this`.

Comment: React says it's doing the biding for me already "Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See DatePicker"

Comment: I see that you're using props in your getIntialState which is only invoked once when your component is first created.You might want to stick the formatting logic somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the keyword *this* to your handleSearchChange function.

```
<SearchBar currentDateObj={searchDateObj} handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange.bind(this)}/>
<input type="text" onChange={this.props.handleSearchChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.currentDateObj}/>
```

If you're getting an error like 'Cannot read property 'setState' of null, binding *this* to your function should fix the error.

Comment: this is the response I got
"warning.js:45Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See DatePicker"

Comment: "Warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance. See DatePicker"

Comment: Hmm. I recommend console logging _this_ inside your handleSearchChange function. If the console log shows _this_ referring to the window object or null, then my guess is your _this_ binding is being lost. If the console log instead shows _this_ referring to your DatePicker component, then I'm not sure what's going on.